# python - find specific row attribute with DictReader

Tags: python, csv

I want to find specific row with DictReader.

#### csv file(test.csv)

```
numb, firstname, lastname
1, yong, kim
2, gwang, lee
3, geun, lee 
...
```

#### .py file

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

result = {}
result = defaultdict(lambda: 0, result)

tmp = open('test.csv', 'r')
file = csv.DictReader(tmp)

# what I want
print file[1]['firstname'] # => I want it to be : "gwang"
```

## EDIT

When I run this code, below error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "****.py", line 23, in <module>
    print file[1]['firstname']
AttributeError: DictReader instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What should I do?

cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [it is said on the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

> Returns a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile.

You can't access the rows with `reader_obj[x]` (`__getitem__`) as it is an iterator.

You first have to materialize the iterator as a list:

```
tmp = open('test.csv', 'r')
file = csv.DictReader(tmp)
data = list(file)

print data[1]['firstname']
```

This is of course reads the whole file to RAM which might not be ideal if it is a big file.

It is preferred to just iterate through the reader as it is shown in the documentation.

Comment: Is there any better way or library to perform this job?

Comment: Well the csv module is in Python's standard library. It is reliable and works really well. You were just trying to use it a way it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate through the `DictReader` object you created, i.e `file`.
See this example to understand how one uses the `DictReader`. Basically you are stepping through the `csv` row by row

[From the docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

```
import csv
with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
         print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```

So just use an `if` to check if the current `row` you are on matches your search criterea